# unexpected type; required: variable; found: value

Tags: java, variables, types

I am well aware that this coding has errors (only been at java for 4 weeks) but I have no idea how to fix it.

Edit2: The only error with the code now (that its telling me about at least) is that the required type is variable and it found a value in the following line:
        `if(yearPublished = 0 & monthPublished = 0)`

```
/**
 * This class describes a book.
 * @author Tess Robertson
 * @version 10/06/2014
 */
class Book
{
    /**
     * Instance variables
     */
    private String title;
    private int bookNumber;
    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;
    private int yearPublished;
    private int monthPublished;
    private String monthName;
    /**
    * Default constructor
    */ 
    public Book()
    {
    }
    /**
     * Another constructor
     * @param initialTitle          - the book's title
     * @param initialBookNumber     - the book's ISBN
     * @param initialLastName       - the author's last name
     * @param initialFirstName      - the author's first name
     * @param initialYearPublished  - the book's publication year
     * @param initialMonthPublished - the book's publication month number
     * @param initialMonthName      - the book's publicaton month name
     */
    public Book(String initialTitle, int initialBookNumber, String initialLastName, String initialFirstName, int initialYearPublished, int initialMonthPublished, String initialMonthName)

    {
        title          = initialTitle;
        bookNumber     = initialBookNumber;
        lastName       = initialLastName;
        firstName      = initialFirstName;
        yearPublished  = initialYearPublished;
        monthPublished = initialMonthPublished;
        monthName      = initialMonthName;
    }
    /**
     * @return the book's title
     */
    public String getTitle()
    {
       return title;
    }
    /**
     * @return the book's ISBN
     */
    public int getBookNumber()
    {
        return bookNumber;
    }
    /**
     * @return the author's last name
     */
    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }
    /**
     * @return the author's first name
     */
    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }
    /**
     * @return the book's publication year
     */
    public int getYearPublished()
    {
        return yearPublished;
    }
    /**
     * @return the book's publication month
     */
    public int getMonthPublished()
    {
        return monthPublished;
    }
    /**
     * @return the book's publication month name
     */
    public String getMonthName()
    {
        return monthName;
    }
    /**
     * @return the author's full name
     */
    public String getFullName()
    {
        return firstName+lastName;
    }
    /**
     * Prints the title, ISBN, Author full name, and publication year and date
     */
    public String printDetails()
    {
        if(title!=null||title.length()>3)
        {
            return ("Title: "+title);
        }
        else if(title==null||title.length()<=3)
        {
            return ("Title: "+"invalid text");
        }
        if(bookNumber>=10000&&bookNumber<=20000)
        {
            return ("ISBN: "+bookNumber);
        }
        else if(bookNumber==0)
        {
            return ("ISBN: "+"invalid number");
        }
        if(lastName==null||firstName==null)
        {
            return ("Author: "+"invalid text");                                
        }
        else
        {
            return ("Author: "+firstName+" "+lastName);
        }
        if(yearPublished = 0 & monthPublished = 0)
        {
            return ("Published: "+"invalid number");

        }
        else
        {
            return ("Published: "+monthName+" "+yearPublished);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Recieve a book title
     * @param newTitle - the title entered by the user
     */
    public void setTitle(String newTitle)
    {
        if(newTitle.length()>3)
        {
            newTitle=title;
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Book title must have more than 3 characters.");
        }
    }
    /**
     * Recieve an ISBN
     * @param newBookNumber - the ISBN entered by the user
     */
    public void setBookNumber(int newBookNumber)
    {
        if(newBookNumber>=10000&&newBookNumber<=20000)
        {
            newBookNumber=bookNumber;
        }

        else 
        {
            System.out.println("ISBN must be a number between 10000 and 20000 inclusive.");
        } 
    }
    /**
     * Recieve author's last name
     * @param newLastName - the last name entered by the user
     */
    public void setLastName(String newLastName)
    {
        if(newLastName != "null")
        {
            lastName=newLastName;
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Author's last name cannot be blank.");
        }
    }
     /**
     * Recieve author's first name
     * @param newFirstName - the first name entered by the user 
     */
    public void setFirstName(String newFirstName)
    {
        if(newFirstName != null)
        {
            newFirstName=firstName;
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Author's first name cannot be blank.");
        }
    }
    /**
     * Recieve a publication year
     * @param newYearPublished - the year of publication entered by the user
     */    
    public void setYearPublished(int newYearPublished)
    {
        if(newYearPublished<=2013&&newYearPublished>=1870)
        {
             newYearPublished=yearPublished;
        }
        else
        {
          System.out.println("Year published must be between 1870 and 2013 inclusive.");
        }
    }
    /**
     * Recieve a publication month
     * @param newMonthPublished - the month of publication entered by the user
     */
    public void setMonthPublished(int newMonthPublished)
    {
        if(newMonthPublished>=1&&newMonthPublished<=12)
        {
            newMonthPublished=monthPublished;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Month published must be between 1 and 12 inclusive.");
        }
    }
    /**
     * Set monthName given monthPublished
     */
    public void setMonthName(String monthName)
    {
        if(monthPublished==1)
        {
            monthName="January";
        }
        else if(monthPublished==2)
        {
            monthName="February";
        }
        else if(monthPublished==3)
        {
            monthName="March";
        }
        else if(monthPublished==4)
        {
            monthName="April";
        }
        else if(monthPublished==5)
        {
            monthName="May";
        }
        else if(monthPublished==6)
        {
            monthName="June";
        }
        else if(monthPublished==7)
        {
            monthName="July";
        }
        else if(monthPublished==8)
        {
            monthName="August";
        }
        else if(monthPublished==9)
        {
            monthName="September";
        }
        else if(monthPublished==10)
        {
            monthName="October";
        }
        else if(monthPublished==11)
        {
            monthName="November";
        }
        else if(monthPublished==12)
        {
            monthName="December";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please be more clear, what do you want ? what is the error ? we can't fix whole syntax errors on this code..

Comment: Tell us *what* there errors are, *where* they are, and *remove* the  code that is irrelevant to the issue. This demonstrates literally no effort to narrow down the problem and post a coherent question.

Comment: Also, in almost every single one of your methods, you mix up your parameters with your class properties. For ex, `setBookNumber` sets the *parameter* to the *class property* when it should be the other way around.

Comment: @Tess run your program and copy paste error list that you get so other can help you better.

Comment: It is unreachable because you have an else statement that will execute and return something before that. Was that supposed to be else if? If not, then it will always default to that else statement if the condition in your `if` statement is false.

Comment: This line - `if(title!=null||title.length()>3)` needs to have `&&` in place of `||` - otherwise bad things happen if `title` is `null`.

Comment: @MarGar you should post that as an answer.  It's clearly the correct solution to Tess's problem.

Comment: I suspect that the `return` statements shouldn't actually be `return` statements at all - the requirement is probably to concatenate all these details into one big return string, rather than just jump out of the method at the first matching condition.

Comment: I added it to my answer, though it was added after I answered..Thanks Mr. Wallace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line.

```
if(yearPublished=0&monthPublished=0){
   return ("Published: "+"invalid number");
```

to

```
if(yearPublished == 0 && monthPublished == 0){
    return ("Published: "+"invalid number");
```

I imagine you are now getting your second, unreachable return, error due to you having an else statement above this block of code, which is called when your conditions in your if-else if loops are false. The else portion will always execute if your conditions are false once it reaches it, thus making this block unreachable.

Here is one easy way to return the string that you want. Simply declare a string to return, then keep adding to it and finally return it once you've evaluated all of your conditions.

```
public String printDetails()
{
    String returnString = ""; //declaring a string to build upon to return once finished all conditions.

    if(title !=null)
    {
        returnString += "Title: " + title + " ";
    }
    else if(title == null || title.length() <= 3)
    {
        returnString += "Title: " + "invalid text ";
    }

    if(bookNumber >= 10000 && bookNumber <= 20000)
    {
        returnString += "ISBN: " + bookNumber + " ";
    }
    else if(bookNumber == 0)
    {
        returnString += "ISBN: " + "invalid number ";
    }

    if(lastName == null || firstName == null)
    {
        returnString += "Author: " + "invalid text ";                                
    }
    else if(firstName != null || lastName != null) // changed to not= null.
    {
        returnString += "Author: " + firstName + " " + lastName + " ";
    }

    if(yearPublished == 0 && monthPublished == 0)
    {
        returnString += "Published: " + "invalid number ";

    }
    else if(yearPublished != 0 && monthPublished != 0)
    {
        returnString += "Published: " + monthName + " " + yearPublished;
    }

    return returnString; // now after the string has been built, we will return it.
}
```

Finally:

Your `setMonthName()` method is perfect for a [switch statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html), The example given is actually exactly what you would want to do. You might also want to accept monthPublished as an argument instead of monthName.

Comment: If I do this, it tells me that the first type is boolean and the second is int. They are both int data types.

Comment: monthPublished=0 must be monthPublished==0 if you are checking for zero

Comment: Try the revised code..sorry, was rushing. I didn't notice the other errors.

Comment: Spacing would help her eliminate some errors such as these :) It will also make your code much easier to read.

Comment: How is this wrong? It solved her initial error. I also posted why she was receiving her second error in a comment above.

Comment: @MarGar Because this does not really actually answer the question. There are numerous other issues beyond this.

Comment: You can only answer the question that is asked. Which was why was she getting her initial error, which this answer does solve.

Comment: @MarGar Your answer is correct.  Don't stress about the downvote.  Some people are just trigger-happy.

Comment: @MarGar well I have an else statement about that because I want printDetails() to print a list like this:
Title:
ISBN:
Author:
Published:

Comment: I will revise my answer.